# Java 8 sum and total not found

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

EDIT: Found the solution here: http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/java-8-lambda-tutorial/map-reduce-tutorial.php

I'm following this tutorial:

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/Lambda-QuickStart/index.html

When I get to the part where it's using the sum and average functions, I get the following error:

```
UserAverageTest.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
        double average = users.parallelStream().filter(u -> u.age > 0).map(u -> u.age).average().getAsDouble();
                                                                                      ^
  symbol:   method average()
  location: interface Stream<Double>
```

I get the same error when calling sum.  For some reason it appears that it's using the Stream instead of DoubleStream class.  I'm using the latest jdk with lambda enabled that is linked in the tutorial.

Has anyone hit this issue as well and was able to resolve it?

Here is a simple example that reproduces the problem:

```
class User {
    double age;
    public User(double age) { this.age = age; }
    double getAge() { return age; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<User> users = Arrays.asList(new User(10), new User(20), new User(30));
    double average = users.parallelStream()
                          .filter(u -> u.age > 0)
                          .map(u -> u.age)
                          .average()
                          .getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I thought we had to wait until September to fiddle with JDK 8.

Comment: you can get an early access release

Comment: When working with an early release it may be better to take questions/concerns to a JDK 8 specific help forum....

Comment: JDK 8 early access builds are available at https://jdk8.java.net/ . New early access builds are released every week or so. Of course, don't use this in production, APIs are subject to change, etc. Looks like the tutorial got caught out by some API changes and so it needs to be updated.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to change the map function to return a stream of primitives, for example:

```
double average = users.parallelStream().filter(u -> u.age > 0).mapToDouble(u -> u.age).average().getAsDouble();
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^
```

The underlying reason is that a `Stream<Double>` (returned by `map`) is not a `DoubleStream` (returned by `mapToDouble`). Only the latter has average and sum methods.